# How do I center an icon in an Edit Text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an icon and a hint in an edit text and  i tried to center the contents of the edit text horizontally, but that seems to only work for the hint and not for the icon. The icon is closer to the bottom of the edit text.

this is my code

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
            />
```

Comment: `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`?

Answer (score 0):

I've had no luck using the `drawableStart` property, an alternative is to use `SpannableString` and `ImageSpan` to set your hint by code.

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString(" Password");
string.setSpan(new ImageSpan(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    
EditText password_edittext = findViewById(R.id.password_edittext);
password_edittext.setHint(string);
```

XML:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/password_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove gravity property, I think it will work for you, because you set the height of edit text to wrap content which will automatically make them vertically center.